# Creating an Excel formula that takes the date range from a column

Tags: excel

**I have a table that contains Date column with dates that look like this:**

**Ex:**

[image]

**In the example above the Excel formula should look at the range and show the following output:**

```
1/23/18 - 1/25/18
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are actual dates (and not strings that look like dates), then they are numbers and you can extract the minimum and maximum values in the range, the format them:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(MIN(A1:A10),"DD/MM/YYYY")," - ",TEXT(MAX(A1:A10),"DD/MM/YYYY"))
```

(in the above, I assumed the dates were in `A1:A10`)

Comment: Is there anyway to stop Excel from shifting the range set in the formula if the number of information changes? For example in the formula above if I set the range to A1:50 for both the MAX and MIN I want it to stay that way even if the data its looking at has a range of A1:10. It seems to shift for me

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You may want to post it with more details as a new question